# Dynamically adjust range based on last column in vba

Tags: excel, vba, vba7

I have a table in excel where i am inserting some column, because of that last column is getting changed, I have to detect the last column and set it as a range in vba

I have written code to find the last column and convert it to alphabet, however i am not able to set it as a range.

```
Public Function ColumnLetter(ColumnNumber As Long) As String
ColumnLetter = Split(Cells(1, ColumnNumber).Address(True, False), "$")(0)
End Function

Dim Rng As Range
Dim LastColumn, LastRow As Long
Dim Str As String

LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
LastColumn = Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Str = ColumnLetter(LastColumn)
'Set Rng = Range("M7:M" & LastRow)
```

I want to write Commented line as

```
Set Rng = Range( & Str & "7" & LastRow)
```

To make it dynamic
How can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, change `Str` to something else; you're shadowing the [`Str`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/str-function) function.

```
Dim colLetter As String
colLetter = ColumnLetter(LastColumn)
```

Then concatenate as necessary:

```
Set Rng = Range(colLetter & "7:" & colLetter & LastRow)
```

Note that you can skip using the column letter and just use `Cells` with the column index.

```
Set Rng = Range(Cells(7, LastColumn), Cells(LastRow, LastColumn))
```

Answer (score 1):

As others pointed out, Str isn't the best variable name. Let's say you change it to "ColLtr" ... then your specific answer is `Range(ColLtr & "7:" & ColLtr & LastRow)`

However, might I suggest another tack?

If you are trying to set the range as the lower right corner of the used range, use:

```
With {sheet}.UsedRange
Set Rng = .Cells(.Rows.Count,.Columns.Count)
End With
```

(substitute {sheet} with `WorkSheets("MySheet")` or `ActiveSheet` or however you prefer to specify the worksheet.)

If you need the entire column, adjust it to:

```
With {sheet}.UsedRange
Set Rng = .Columns(.Columns.Count)
End With
```

BUT ... if you "Format Range as a Table" (creating a ListObject), you can bypass VBA altogether and use `[TableName[ColumnHeader]]`, either in VBA or in your worksheet formulae. Of course, "TableName" and "ColumnHeader" would be specific to your table's name and the actual text in your column header.

Comment: A side note: `UsedRange` is [unreliable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-excel-with-vba) when attempting to find the last row/column of data.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I tend to still use it and make sure unused columns and rows are fully deleted, so i don't think a whole lot about that quirk (and since I typically write for very limited audiences, too).